# serialize and deserialise using boost binary_iarchive from sstream

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

Finally , After lot of struggle i found a way to serialise and deserialize  the `std::map<int,map<int,structute values>` and iam able to print the values.

Would you please clarify the doubts i have pertaining to the code below

> 1. Is `void serialize(archive & ar,  const unsigned int version)` function used for both serialising and deserialising
> 2. Can we have separate functions for both serialise and deserialise in each class and structs
> 3. Can the same function be utilised for creating xml also , or is it a neat way to have separate serialise and deserialise functionality for xml

```
 #include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
 #include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
 #include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <map>
 #include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
   
struct values
{
    std::string name;
    std::string sex;
    values():name("dummy"),sex("dummy"){} ;
    template<class archive>
    void serialize(archive & ar,  const unsigned int version)
    {
      ar & name ;
      ar & sex ;
    }
};
class Myclass 
{
public:
    
  Myclass()
  {
    values val1;
    e_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,val1) ) ;
    e_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,val1) ) ;
    p_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,e_group) ) ;
    p_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,e_group) ) ;
  }
  template<class archive>
  void serialize(archive & ar,  const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & e_group ;
    ar & p_group;
  }
  typedef   std::map<int,values> groups;
  typedef   std::map<int,groups> Pgroups;
  groups  e_group;
  Pgroups p_group;
};

int main() {
    char buf[256];

    Myclass obj;

    std::stringstream os(std::ios_base::binary| std::ios_base::out| std::ios_base::in);
    {
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(os, boost::archive::no_header);
        oa << obj ;
      // oa << make_binary_object(&e_group, sizeof(e_group));
    }
   
   //print binary data
    std::string data = os.str();
    for (uint8_t ch : data) {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(ch) << " ";
    }
    


    Myclass t2;
    {       
        memcpy(buf, os.str().data(), os.str().length());
        if(memcmp(buf, os.str().data(), os.str().length()) != 0)
          printf("memcpy error\n");
        std::stringstream is(std::string(buf, buf+os.str().length() ), std::ios_base::binary| std::ios_base::out| std::ios_base::in);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(is, boost::archive::no_header);
        ia >> t2;
    }

   for(auto &i:t2.p_group){
       std::cout<<"\n"<<i.first<<"\n";
        for(auto &j:i.second){
          std::cout<<"\t"<<j.first<<"\t"<<j.second.name<<"\t"<<j.second.sex<<"\n";
        }
   } 
   return 0;
}
```

> Update : i have updated richard's code and added a function to deserilaize the binary

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

#include <map>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>


struct values
{
    std::string name;
    std::string sex;
    values():name("dummy"),sex("dummy"){} ;

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER();

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const
    {
        // note, version is always the latest when saving
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(name);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(sex);
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(name);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(sex);
    }
};
class Myclass
{
public:

    Myclass()
    {
        values val1;
        e_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,val1) ) ;
        e_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,val1) ) ;
        p_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,e_group) ) ;
        p_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,e_group) ) ;
    }

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER();

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const
    {
        // note, version is always the latest when saving
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(e_group);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(p_group);
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(e_group);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(p_group);
    }

    typedef   std::map<int,values> groups;
    typedef   std::map<int,groups> Pgroups;
    groups  e_group;
    Pgroups p_group;
};

template<class Archive, class Object>
std::string serialise_to_string(Object const& assetlist)
{
    auto os = std::ostringstream(std::ios::binary);
    Archive arch { os, boost::archive::no_header };
    arch << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(assetlist);
    return os.str();
};


std::ostream& dump(std::ostream& os, std::string const& s)
{
    const char *sep = "";
    for (uint8_t ch : s) {
        std::cout << sep << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(ch);
        sep = " ";
    }
    return os;
}

template<class Archive , class Object>
void deserialise_to_obj(std::string const &s1,Object &outObj)
{
    std::stringstream is( s1, std::ios_base::binary| std::ios_base::out| std::ios_base::in);
    Archive arch { is, boost::archive::no_header };
    arch >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(outObj);
};


int main() {
    
    Myclass obj ;
    std::string  s1 = serialise_to_string<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>(obj);
    dump(std::cout, s1) << std::endl << std::endl;
    
    auto s2 = serialise_to_string<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>(obj);
   
   //Save xml to a file
    std::ofstream ofs("output.xml");
    ofs << s2 << std::endl << std::endl;
    
    //Deserialize the binary data to object
    Myclass outObj;
    deserialise_to_obj<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>(s1,outObj); 
    
    //Print the object 
    for(auto &i:outObj.p_group){
       std::cout<<"\n"<<i.first<<"\n";
        for(auto &j:i.second){
          std::cout<<"\t"<<j.first<<"\t"<<j.second.name<<"\t"<<j.second.sex<<"\n";
        }
    } 
}
```

code compiled using [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b00ce14c5ae853c)

Please suggest . advice me if my approach is wrong

I would want to thank @sehe and @richard helping me with boost.

Thanks
Tejas

Answer (score 2):

First, don't do this:

```
    memcpy(buf, os.str().data(), os.str().length());
    if(memcmp(buf, os.str().data(), os.str().length()) != 0)
```

That's just created 4 separate copies of a string.

Now the questions:

> Is void serialize(archive & ar,  const unsigned int version) function used for both serialising and deserialising

Yes

> Can we have separate functions for both serialise and deserialise in each class and structs

Yes

> Can the same function be utilised for creating xml also , or is it a neat way to have separate serialise and deserialise functionality for xml

Yes

You want the `xml_oarchive` and the macros `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER` and `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP`

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>


struct values
{
    std::string name;
    std::string sex;
    values():name("dummy"),sex("dummy"){} ;

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER();

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const
    {
        // note, version is always the latest when saving
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(name);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(sex);
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(name);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(sex);
    }
};
class Myclass
{
public:

    Myclass()
    {
        values val1;
        e_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,val1) ) ;
        e_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,val1) ) ;
        p_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,e_group) ) ;
        p_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,e_group) ) ;
    }

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER();

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const
    {
        // note, version is always the latest when saving
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(e_group);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(p_group);
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(e_group);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(p_group);
    }

    typedef   std::map<int,values> groups;
    typedef   std::map<int,groups> Pgroups;
    groups  e_group;
    Pgroups p_group;
};

template<class Archive, class Object>
std::string serialise_to_string(Object const& o)
{
    auto os = std::ostringstream(std::ios::binary);
    Archive arch { os, boost::archive::no_header };
    arch << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(o);
    return os.str();
};

std::ostream& dump(std::ostream& os, std::string const& s)
{
    const char *sep = "";
    for (uint8_t ch : s) {
        std::cout << sep << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(ch);
        sep = " ";
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {
    char buf[256];

    Myclass obj;

    auto s1 = serialise_to_string<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>(obj);
    dump(std::cout, s1) << std::endl << std::endl;

    auto s2 = serialise_to_string<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>(obj);
    std::cout<< s2 << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 02 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 02 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 02 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 75 6d 6d 79

<o class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <e_group class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <count>2</count>
        <item_version>0</item_version>
        <item class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <first>1</first>
            <second class_id="3" tracking_level="0" version="0">
                <name>dummy</name>
                <sex>dummy</sex>
            </second>
        </item>
        <item>
            <first>2</first>
            <second>
                <name>dummy</name>
                <sex>dummy</sex>
            </second>
        </item>
    </e_group>
    <p_group class_id="4" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <count>2</count>
        <item_version>0</item_version>
        <item class_id="5" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <first>1</first>
            <second>
                <count>2</count>
                <item_version>0</item_version>
                <item>
                    <first>1</first>
                    <second>
                        <name>dummy</name>
                        <sex>dummy</sex>
                    </second>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <first>2</first>
                    <second>
                        <name>dummy</name>
                        <sex>dummy</sex>
                    </second>
                </item>
            </second>
        </item>
        <item>
            <first>2</first>
            <second>
                <count>2</count>
                <item_version>0</item_version>
                <item>
                    <first>1</first>
                    <second>
                        <name>dummy</name>
                        <sex>dummy</sex>
                    </second>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <first>2</first>
                    <second>
                        <name>dummy</name>
                        <sex>dummy</sex>
                    </second>
                </item>
            </second>
        </item>
    </p_group>
</o>
```

Comment: Why the split load/save? The implementation is the same, which makes it unnecessary overhead

Comment: @sehe I thought that's what he asked for - yup, question 2.

Comment: He asked "Is void serialize(archive & ar,  const unsigned int version) function used for both serialising and deserialising" - the answer is "Yes"

Comment: I'm also _really_ confused where you get the idea he "wants" the xml archive. (I happen to know from other questions that he wants that _as well_, but that's nowhere in the question?)

Comment: @sehe that was q1, which I have failed to answer.

Comment: @sehe are we looking at the same version of the question? xml is asked about in q3

Comment: Mmm. Okay. I concede that point. You already had my +1 of course :) It's funny because there's some inconsistency between the questions OP has posted earlier :)

Comment: @sehe  As Richard specified , my question was ,  Can the same function be utilised for serialising and  deserialising  binary and xml both .So that I could create anyone of them when needed.

Comment: @RichardHodges i have made slight changes in ur code to 1. deserialise and print the object and 2. Save xml in  a file and updated my main post. Also,  Can we not have the serialise_to_string function as a member function of the class ?

Comment: @LearningCpp you can put it wherever you want. You'll find that it's more versatile as a free function

Comment: So if it's a member function , we can have  load , save , serialize_to_string and deserialise_to_string  as a part of class myClass and structure too

Comment: @LearningCpp you can, and it's a common assumption that this is a good idea. However, the more you can implement common operations as free functions, the more flexible and maintainable you'll find your code is.

Comment: @RichardHodges Since these are common functions , do u think we need to compromise on some things  , like xml tag names , it tags  the values with  object name and we can't change them and if we change the functionality to ` ar & make_nvp("myGroup",e_group);` for having customised tagging , will it still be good enough to create binary objects

Comment: i have tried the code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e6cac04d8566469 and it works fine, but i would like to understand what's the use of tag names when we create a binary archive, are the tag names  it ignored ?

Comment: @LearningCpp yes. I told you all of that [more than 24h ago](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36355005#36355005). I think you should spend more time reading, allowing time to understand, and less posting more duplicate questions on [SO]. [sic](http://i.imgur.com/pe9dLkW.png). Also, testing things out builds understanding like nothing else.